# TabLayout does not display tabs items

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try connect TabLayout with ViewPager2 via TabLayoutMediator but items [not displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQllx.png)

How i can fix it ?

Here is my code :

```
class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

override fun createFragment(position: Int) = SalesOfficesFragment()
```

}

```
    private fun initViews() {
    val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(context as FragmentActivity)
    binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
    }.attach()
}
```

Comment: share scren XML and tabs XML code and try adding scroll in tabs maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `tab.text` in the `TabLayoutMediator`:

```
private fun initViews() {
    val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(context as FragmentActivity)
    binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
        // Set the title of the tabs 
        when (position) {
            0 -> tab.text = "First element"
            else -> tab.text = "Other elements"
        }
    }.attach()
}
```