# Set color of individual TabBar Tab in .Net MAUI

Tags: maui

I would like to change the color of a specific Tab in a .Net MAUI TabBar.  I've been able to change the whole TabBarBackgroundColor as below.  But how can I override the color of a single Tab? For example if I wanted the BackgroundColor of "TAB 2" to be Bisque.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="AliceBlue" >

    <TabBar IsVisible="True"
            IsEnabled="True"
            >
        <ShellContent
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"
            Title="TAB 1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>

        <ShellContent
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"
            Title="TAB 2"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I believe that platform-specific code may be needed.  I'm targeting iOS and Android.

Comment: The tabbar is the a cross-platform control and there is no a such api can set the item's background color.

Comment: Are there any options to do this using platform specific code?

Comment: Did you want to do this on all the platforms?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I'm targeting iOS and Android.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. For the android, you can use the [shell's custom render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571704/how-to-set-shell-upper-tabs-to-take-full-width-shell-xamarin) in the [.net maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) to get the TabLayout and use the [TabLayoutMediator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771601/17455524) to set the tab's background color.